# Django hstore field in sqlite

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, django-models

I am using sqlite (development stage) database for my django project. I would like to store a dictionary field in a model. In this respect, i would like to use django-hstore field in my model.

My question is, can i use django-hstore dictionary field in my model even though i am using sqlite as my database?

As per my understanding django-hstore can be used along with PostgreSQL (Correct me if i am wrong). Any suggestion in the right direction is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hstore is specific to Postgres. It won't work on sqlite.

If you just want to store JSON, and don't need to search within it, then you can use one of the many third-party JSONField implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input, but i would like to search or query the dictionary field in my database. Is there any other alternative to this json field?